# Terminal Server Logging Software

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, terminal, windows-terminal-services

I have recently been trying to find software to monitor users' activities on our terminal server. After a quick search, I found http://www.softactivity.com/tsm.aspx. Has anyone ever heard of or used this program? I just want to make sure this company is legit and the software runs efficiently. The server I would be installing it on has about 40-50 users on it. I am hoping the software has some type of setting to only monitor certain users, because i would hate to waste resources.

If this is not good software, does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of or used the product you referenced in your question, but I have used this:

http://www.observeit-sys.com/

Comment: +1 - we've used their software too, but it was a bitch to get configured, and their tech support gave up on us I think (we were still in the evaulation stage). It's also not cheap if you want the pro version for full retention.